# Laravel link storage folder outside of project for cpanel hosted application

Tags: php, laravel

I hosted my laravel application to cpanel. I want to make link to storage folder which have at my application folder at public_html/private/storage to outside of my application I meant directly at public_html folder here is bellow is my folder structure

```
private
----app
----controller
----public
etc
----storage
```

I want the storage folder link from outside of private at my cpanel so this should be link from public_html folder. I am trying to run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

but this creating folder at private/public folder. please help me for this

Answer (score 0):

behind laravel's storage:link is just a symlink.
if you have access to shell, you can use this command:

```
ln -s storage/app/public ../etc/storage
```